# How to change Image starting position without losing Boundary area in Fabricjs

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, fabricjs

Here, i have to achieve Image resizing within boundary/selected area in fabric-JS. 
I have create Replace existing Image with New Image with using Fabric-JS.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkt91/r09mxdyc/1/)

Image replacing:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

function addImage(imgLink) {
    fabric.Image.fromURL(imgLink, function(img) {
        img.set({ 'left': 50 });
        img.set({ 'top': 50 });
        img.scaleToWidth(100);
        img.scaleToHeight(100);

        var objs = canvas.getObjects();
        if (objs.length) {
            objs.forEach(function(e) {
                if (e && e.type === 'image') {
                    e._element.src = imgLink;
                    canvas.renderAll();
                }
            });
        } else canvas.add(img);
    });
}

addImage('http://fabricjs.com/lib/pug.jpg');

// file upload
var span = document.querySelector('#span');
span.onchange = function(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(file) {
        addImage(file.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

But, I need to Upload Image and modify its position without changing selected area.

[image: Initial Picture]

Original Image:

[image: Original Image]

I need to change/resize position of image without changing Selected/Boundary area. For example, One image have 50x50 pixels but its will changes position within 50x50 pixel.Is it possible in fabricjs events?.

Thanks for your advance help.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

function addImage(imgLink) {
    fabric.Image.fromURL(imgLink, function(img) {
        img.set({ 'left': 50 });
        img.set({ 'top': 50 });
        img.scaleToWidth(100);
        img.scaleToHeight(100);
    
        var objs = canvas.getObjects();
        if (objs.length) {
            objs.forEach(function(e) {
                if (e && e.type === 'image') {
                    e._element.src = imgLink;
                    canvas.renderAll();
                }
            });
        } else canvas.add(img);
    });
}

addImage('http://fabricjs.com/lib/pug.jpg');

// file upload
var span = document.querySelector('#span');
span.onchange = function(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(file) {
        addImage(file.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border:1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<span><input type="file" name="" id="span"></span>
```

Comment: You want to use zoomed image in that area??

Comment: No, I need to changed that position of image not exactly zoomed image